# Is there a way to use the name of the imported file in naming a new created file?

Tags: python, file, rename, naming

In my program I import a certain file, at the end I create a file in which I save the outputs. I would like to use the name of the imported file (with some additions) as the name of the newly created file.

Since I have a large amount of files to import, I would like to do this in order to have a better overview of which files were created based on which files.

For example: I open a file with `file=open(‘summer.txt’)` and I would like to use the 'summer' of the original file and just add the year, the name of the new file would be ‘summer2020.txt’.

I would like to automatically detect the name of the imported file, add the year and that would be the name of my new file. (the addition to the name ('2020') would be the same for every opened file)

I’ m still new to python, so I don‘t know if this is possible or if there is a better way of doing it. Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: What ho you tried? Have you checked out [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) functions? I think you are looking for `basename`

Comment: Use os.walk to get the file names, and you can replace the hardcoded filename with a variable, and do the required operations on that variable. For Ex., in-file = 'summer.txt’ , in-file+='2020' ( you can use datetime module for getting the years).
Then use the variable in-file while export a file.

Comment: Please note, that you can upvote answers (↑-Symbol). This especially makes sense for the answer which you have accepted as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.9, you can use `pathlib` and the new `with_stem` method

```
file_path=Path('summer.txt')
new_file_path = file_path.with_stem(file_path.stem+'2020')
```

Advantage of using pathlib is that it supports multiple platforms (win/osx/linux) and their different ways of specifying paths. Also allows you to easily split the file name in to the stem `summer` and suffix `.txt`.

For versions of python like 3.6.5, you can do the following instead

```
new_file_path = file_path.with_name(f"{file_path.stem}2020{file_path.suffix}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to automatically get the current year:

```
from datetime import datetime
curdate = datetime.now()
curyear = str(curdate.year)
file = open('summer'+curyear+'.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, I know how to add the year, I m looking for a way how to automatically put the 'summer' part in the name of the output file.

Answer (score 0):

As you have many files you maybe want something like

```py
import glob, shutil
myfiles = glob.glob("*.txt")
for fname in myfiles:
    basename = fname[:-4] # drop .txt at the end
    newname = f"{basname}2020.txt"
    shutil.copy(fname, newname)
```